# Using CoreData to save array containing dictionaries

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I'm trying to use CoreData framework inside an iOS app for the first time and I have some troubles with it.

I have a kind of complex type of array, containing tuples that contains dictionaries:

`let DataSet: [( Float, Float, [String : String])] = ...`

I created an `NSManagedObjectContext` and an `NSManagedObject`, I added the `DataSet` array to the `NSManagedObject`, but when I try to save the 1st `NSManagedObjectContext`, the app is crashing.

That's not happening using normal arrays but only with more complex ones like the one above.

Is there a way to deal with that problem? Do I need to adjust my xcdatamodel?

I would appreciate any help a lot.

Comment: Make use of Core Data properly and create entities instead if possible, the dictionary is one (A) and the tuple is another (B) with a one-to-one relationship between A and B

Comment: Do you really need to save the data as a complex array, or can you more simply construct that array dynamically from each element in the array, persisted (saved) separately as discrete attributes, using the CoreData framework?

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need to declare 2 separate entities. One for Floats and another for Dictionary.
2. Then create "One to Many" relation ship between Float entity and Dictionary. It will look like this,

   [image: xcdatamodeld screenshot]
3. Then you need to convert your tuple into these 2 entities, Like this,

   ```swift
   dataSet.forEach{ (member) in
       let tuple = Test.(context: mainContext)
       tuple.first = member.0
       tuple.second = member.1

       let dictionary = member.2
       dictionary.forEach{ (key, value) in
           let dick = Dick.(context: mainContext)
           dick.key = key
           dick.value = value
           tuple.addToContains(dick)
       }
   }
   ```
4. Finally you need to save the values.

   ```
   if mainContext.hasChanges {
       do {
           try mainContext.save()
       } catch {
           print(\(error))
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Post code as text, not as images. Text is searchable and can be copied into a text editor or Xcode while images are pretty useless to work with.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Sorry. This time code formatter was giving me some trouble in formatting the code. So not able to post it that way.

Comment: Then find out what the problem is and solve it, no images please.

Comment: The problem was, it looks like code formatter won't accept 2 forEach inside one another. Tried to fix it for 15 min. Nothing worked except this one.

Comment: The formatter is not intelligent - code is presented on screen in two ways that I am aware of - as a whole line - four (4) blank character spaces as a prefix - or as a word within a paragraph - contained within this character `. All the information you need to properly format your answers is contained in the SO site. [How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) I edited your answer in 4 by writing the code in your image. It needed eight (8) character spaces before it converted to “code” format. I suspect this is due to it falling within the numeric dot format block.

Comment: @andrewbuilder Thanks a lot. Now I replaced code images with code snippets.